# Downgrade FlashBuilder project

Tags: apache-flex, ide, flash-builder, downgrade

I have a Flash-Builder Flex project that was created (or upgraded) using FB 4.7.

I am using Flash-Builder 4, and the IDE doesn't recognize the project as a Flex project, so I can't import it into the IDE.

What are my options here? Is there a quick way of downgrading the project to a FB4 project?

Comment: are you using fxp? make fxp and then import.

Comment: @ketan, no fxp. I've never had fxp and don't know what it is or how to create it. Another project i have has a .project and a .flexProperties file and is imported without any problem.

Comment: U can export fxp from file menu and click on Export -> Flash builder project. And import from File -> Import Flash builder project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- SOLUTION 1 : verify your ".project" file: check if the project description is ok

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>MyProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.flexbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.flexnature</nature>
        <nature>com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.actionscriptnature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

2- SOLUTION 2 : put your project into your workspace and create a new project with the same name of your project folder name (for exp: if your project folder name "myproject" - create a new flex project with name "myproject"), 
this will create a new flex project with your old source code.

Comment: Solution 2 was an obvious and simple option which I was trying to avoid, as I was hoping to get the configuration from the previous project. But as I had to move on and the stakes were not high, I went for it. Thanks.